# Get Visa using approval letter

Tags: visa, working-visas, indian-citizens, malta

I'm in the process of traveling to Malta for work.

I had my client apply for me and he **submitted all my docs**(listed [here](http://www.vfsglobal.com/malta/india/Long-Work.html)) to Identity Malta (their foreign affairs people). My application was accepted and I received an approval letter. I am now to use this letter to get my passport stamped with a visa.

But I'm not sure on how to go about doing this.

Should I go the Embassy or VFS? I emailed the Malta Embassy but they still haven't got back to me. And I only have 50 days remaining for me to complete this process.

I contacted VFS and they were talking to me as if I'm a new applicant, asking for all the docs I already submitted. I tried explaining to them but they wouldn't understand.

This is what the letter looks like:
[image: Letter]

Comment: It says to go to the [Maltese consulate (Delhi)](https://foreignaffairs.gov.mt/en/Embassies/Hc_New_Delhi/Pages/HC_New_Delhi.aspx) for your visa, then go to Malta (before March 13) to complete the rest of the process (the four bullet points).

Comment: @Dorothy I'm on my way to Delhi, 1600 KM away from home. No appointment what so ever was booked. Hope things work out

Comment: All should be well. I'm sure you have this: the High Commission is located at N60 Panchsheel Park, phone +91 11 4767 4900. The hours are Monday to Friday from 0900hrs to 1700hrs. There is a note that _Any visa-related queries must be submitted by email. Information related to visa applications cannot be provided via the emergency mobile number._     maltahighcommission.newdelhi@gov.mt Bon chance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the letter you received, it directs you to visit the Maltese Consulate (Delhi) to obtain your visa.

High Commission of Malta
N60 Panchsheel Park, New Delhi, Delhi 110017
Hours: Monday to Friday from 0900hrs to 1700hrsbr>
Email: maltahighcommission.newdelhi@gov.mt

You must then travel to Malta within 60 days (i.e., before March 13), to complete the remainder of the process:

Attend the department for Citizenship and Expatriate Affairs,submit your biometrics, and present:

- your residence in Malta
- local health insurance coverage
- your qualifications and reference letters (originals)
- chest X-ray